# Getting error org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.aerospike.spark.sql.sources.v2.DefaultSource could not be instantiated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aerospike

Hello I am running spark 2.4.2 which is using scala 2.12.8 in my local machine.

I have written a simple program to write some data to aerospike db (Aerospike Community Edition build 5.2.0.6) using the connector version 2.8.0

https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/connect/processing/spark/installation.html

```
package mypackage

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.aerospike.spark.sql.AerospikeConnection
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object UpsWriteStandalone extends App {
  val asHost = "127.0.0.1:3000"

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .set("aerospike.seedhost", asHost)
    .set("aerospike.namespace", "test")
    .set("aerospike.log.level", "info")

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

  val num_records=1000
  val rand = scala.util.Random


  val schema: StructType = new StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("id", IntegerType, nullable = false),
      StructField("name", StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = false),
      StructField("salary",IntegerType, nullable = false)
    ))

  val inputDF = {
    val inputBuf=  new ArrayBuffer[Row]()
    for ( i <- 1 to num_records){
      val name = "name"  + i
      val age = i%100
      val salary = 50000 + rand.nextInt(50000)
      val id = i
      val r = Row(id, name, age,salary)
      inputBuf.append(r)
    }
    val inputRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inputBuf.toSeq)
    spark.createDataFrame(inputRDD,schema)
  }

  inputDF.show(10)

  inputDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
//    .format("aerospike") //aerospike specific format
    .format("com.aerospike.spark.sql")
    .option("aerospike.writeset", "scala_input_data1") //write to this set
    .option("aerospike.updateByKey", "id") //indicates which columns should be used for construction of primary key
    .option("aerospike.sendKey", "true")
    .save()

  spark.sparkContext.stop()
}
```

I have added the jar file using intelliJ, and the code compiles, but on running I am getting this error

```
exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.aerospike.spark.sql.sources.v2.DefaultSource could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:284)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:382)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:382)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:246)
    at com.truecaller.data.ads.adsupswrite.UpsWriteStandalone$.delayedEndpoint$com$truecaller$data$ads$adsupswrite$UpsWriteStandalone$1(UpsWriteStandalone.scala:55)
    at com.truecaller.data.ads.adsupswrite.UpsWriteStandalone$delayedInit$body.apply(UpsWriteStandalone.scala:12)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at com.truecaller.data.ads.adsupswrite.UpsWriteStandalone$.main(UpsWriteStandalone.scala:12)
    at com.truecaller.data.ads.adsupswrite.UpsWriteStandalone.main(UpsWriteStandalone.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class
    at com.aerospike.spark.sql.sources.v2.DefaultSource.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 35 more
```

I am not able to figure out the issue here

I am using version 2.4.6 for spark client library with scala version 2.12.11

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/connect/processing/spark/configuration.html), this connector would require a feature key file (and the Enterprise Edition of the server).